# Node js packages for modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, express

***Description:***
        I have a node js project, I have package models(which contains module with my model object) , have routes package (where module with routes handler functions stored), and app.js file with 'express' configurations and http server.

**Question is:** How can I import model object from models package to routes package, index.js module?

**index.js:**

```
var ArticleProvider = require('smth goes here').ArticleProvider;

var articleProvider= new ArticleProvider();

exports.index = function(req, res){
    articleProvider.findAll(function(error, docs){
        //console.log(error)
        res.send(docs);
  });
};
```

**mymodel.js**

```
ArticleProvider = function(){};
ArticleProvider.prototype.dummyData = [];
ArticleProvider.prototype.findAll = function(callback){
    callback(null, this.dummyData);
};

ArticleProvider.prototype.save = function(articles, callback) {
    var article = null;
    if (typeof(articles.length) == "undefined") { articles = [articles]; }

    //callback();
};

exports.ArticleProvider = ArticleProvider;
```

**Note:** I can import anything from bottom level(for example: if I would have models package inside routes package. **Example:** `require("./models/mymodel.js")`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution is**

```
var ArticleProvider = require('../models/articleprovider.js').ArticleProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at npm link https://npmjs.org/doc/link.html

It's allow you to build a packages as a dependency, into node_modules, and then you can require it wherever you want

Comment: I am new at node.js, is it nice practice to store models this way?

Comment: yes this is one way to do this. an other option you could use is to publish you package into npm database and then "npm install" it, or store it into your how repo (github, etc)

Comment: We're not talking about a general package but about a module that's part of a larger application.